# Single httpclient at same time accessed by two async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using Single HTTP client for whole app to manage session on server side .
It works fine until two async task access same HTTP client at the same time.
I got this error .
"Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated"
What to do in such situation. ?

Comment: please show your code !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342364/error-in-running-two-async-task?noredirect=1#comment25160645_17342364

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom HttpClient, that uses a `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`

```
public class MyGreatHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

       (...)

        return new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpparams, registry);
    }
}
```